# Symfony2 - auto install assets on Netbeans

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, assets

Now when i test my aplication, i need to run the command on netbeans:

```
assets:install
```

I hate doing things over and over again... because symfony2 needs to run this command to put the modified files in the correct path.

Is there a way to run that command or change the configuration files?

Using --symlink  i get this message:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                            
  The symlink() function is not available on your system. You need to install the assets without the --symlink option.
```

SOLVED!

My Windows version (XP) does not support --symlink. I found a Link shell extension for Windows that can do that.
Here is the program and the documentation, very easy to use it!

[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#introduction)

Thanks to all, it was very helpful.

Comment: Symfony uses symbolic links so you don't need to run the command everytime you modify a file.

Comment: To create a symlink to each bundle instead of copying its assets, use the `--symlink` option

Comment: The symlink() function is not available on your system. You need to install the assets without the --symlink option. [InvalidArgumentException]

Comment: @Patrick are you running a windows version prior to Vista? http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php

Comment: @cheesemacfly I'm using XP, is that a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!

My Windows version (XP) does not support --symlink. I found a Link shell extension for Windows that can do that. Here is the program and the documentation, very easy to use it!

[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#introduction)

Thanks to all, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--symlink` switch on the `assets:install` command:

```
$ php app/console assets:install -h
Usage:
 assets:install [--symlink] [--relative] target

Arguments:
 target      The target directory (usually "web")

Options:
 --symlink   Symlinks the assets instead of copying it
 --relative  Make relative symlinks

Help:
 The assets:install command installs bundle assets into a given
 directory (e.g. the web directory).

 php app/console assets:install web

 A "bundles" directory will be created inside the target directory, and the
 "Resources/public" directory of each bundle will be copied into it.

 To create a symlink to each bundle instead of copying its assets, use the
 --symlink option:

 php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Comment: I found about --symlink. Sorry i have forgot to put on the question..now im going to edit it. but seems like i can't use it.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the `--symlink` argument is your solution.

Assuming you are using windows, what you need to do is execute the command from a command window that is running with Admin level privileges. You can google for how to do this for your OS as there are better ways on different versions of Windows and you didn't say what you were using.

Comment: @lcode4food I'm using XP, as cheesemacfly said, seems like windows versions prior vista are missing --symlink?

Comment: I never knew Windows supported symlinks. This changes everything!